# Evaluating the infinite series $\begin{align}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2^{n-1})^\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}\end{align}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2^{n-1})^\frac{n(n+1)}{2}} = (1) +\left(\frac{1}{2^{1+2}}\right) +\left(\frac{1}{(2^2)^{1+2+3}}\right) +\left(\frac{1}{(2^3)^{1+2+3+4}}\right) +\ldots$$
I have tried
$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{2}(n-1)n(n+1)=\frac{1}{8}\left[(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)-(n-2)(n-1)n(n+1)\right]\end{align}$$
and hence
$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{2^\frac{(n-1)n(n+1)}{2}}=\frac{2^\frac{(n-2)(n-1)n(n+1)}{8}}{2^\frac{(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)}{8}}\end{align}$$

But it seems it’s still not working.

The answer is given by $17/10$, but Wolfram gives $1.12524$.

I wondered if a summation can be an irrational number.
How can I evaluate it? Or it is a wrong problem?

Comment: Definitely the sum is an irrational number.  Its binary expansion is non-repeating (it has an infinite number of 1s but the proportion of them is 0).

Comment: Probably no closed form, at least in terms of the usual functions. Is there a reason you'd expect a closed formula?

Comment: Becuase I found that $\begin{align}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}\end{align}$ can be expressed by Jacobi theta function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Too long for a comment*

After @Erick Wong's comment, consider the partial sums
$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^p \frac 1{2^{\frac{(n-1)n(n+1)}2}}$$ and look at their binary forms
$$S_2=\frac{1001_2}{1000_2}$$
$$S_3=\frac{1001000000001_2}{1000000000000_2}$$
$$S_4=\frac{1001000000001000000000000000001_2}{100000000000000000000000
   0000000_2}$$
$$S_5=\frac{10010000000010000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000
   01_2}{10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
   00000_2}$$

Counting the proportion of $1$'s in the numerator

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & \text{proportion of } 1's \\
 10 & 0.0201613 \\
 20 & 0.0050113 \\
 30 & 0.0022245 \\
 40 & 0.0012507 \\
 50 & 0.0008003 \\
 60 & 0.0005557 \\
 70 & 0.0004082 \\
 80 & 0.0003125 \\
  90 & 0.0002469 \\
 100 & 0.0002000 \\
 200 & 0.0000500 \\
 300 & 0.0000222 \\
 400 & 0.0000125 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: wow, thanks for checking that ~